# Terminal "Permission Denied" - Need more info on error message

Tags: file-system, terminal, file-permissions

I am trying to run an executable from the android terminal with root permissions, but I am constantly receiving the following error:

```
[ExecutableName] : permission denied
```

I am confirmed to be loged in as root.  I see the # sign before my prompt and I can run root commands such as chmod.  I saw that the [android shell guide](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Android-Shell-Command-Reference) says

> "The built-in shell has very limited error handling. When you type a command name >incorrectly it will say "permission denied", even though the real problem is that it >couldn't find the command:"

Does anyone know how to get more information on this "permission denied" error?

Comment: Can you run `ls -l` from the directory the executable is in and post that?

Comment: Here is what I ran, I just really want more info on what happens when i run it. `---xrwxr-x 1 system sdcard_r  76 Oct 3 2007 doukutsu`

Comment: Hm, the `sdcard_r` is interesting. Is the binary on your SD card? I know some devices (but possibly not all) simply won't let you run an executable if it's on the external storage. You could try moving it to `/data/local` or somewhere similar and see if that helps. I don't know that there's a way to simply get more info from the shell as to *why* you're getting `permission denied`, though.

Comment: Do you have SuperUser installed? What does the log say?

Comment: @MatthewRead It says "terminal emulator allowed"

Comment: @eldarerathis That gets me to some different error messages at least which i think is promising.  I now get ./doukutsu not found or running its associated bin, ./doukutsu.bin: 1 Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")").  I think this file might have some errors, but i think for the purpose of this post that got me around the error thank you.

Comment: I got the expected `xxx: not found` on both normal and root shell on my Samsung Spica; what's your phone model?

Answer (score 6):

As eldarerathis already mentioned: On many (if not most) devices supporting an SD card, this card is mounted with the `noexec` option -- which means as the name suggests: "no exec from here", i.e. you cannot execute anything from the sdcard.

Again, one solution was already mentioned by eldarerathis: Try a different storage. You've got the power, your device is rooted.

A second approach would be to re-mount the sdcard without the `noexec` option. But there's a good reason why `noexec` is used here; it at least offers an additional level of security. So before using this approach, you should research a bit whether it might trigger unwanted side-effects.

Comment: +1 from me - that's the sole reason why SDcards have the executable bit blocked at the filesystem level, to prevent malicious apps wreaking havoc from another place outside of the ROM i.e. SDcard!